# Is there an bug in dbus?

Tags: java, linux, svn, dbus

My friends，i got a strange error,is anyone can help me?
When i try to get files via svn in a java web project on a ubantu/kyrin linux,it report an error,whitch force shutdown the tomcat server.
The error message is:

```
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed:No such interface[org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties] on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login
dbus[100444]: arguments to dbus_message_iter_apend_basic() were incorrect,assertion "_dbus_check_is_valid_utf8(*strinng_p)" failed in file dbus-message.c line 2754.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-bus lubrary
D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
```

At first,i thought i need to install a svn client in linux,then i found it already has a fully functional svn client.
Then,i tried to update the version of svnkit.jar to 1.10.3,but still is a fail.
I really really dont know how to fix it,looking forward an expert,thank you all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' on object at path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49570593/no-such-interface-org-freedesktop-dbus-properties-on-object-at-path-org-freed)